# Attaching assets if the page contains a table

Tags: 8, theming

I want to attach a CSS file to a page only if it contains a table. I tried

```
function my_assets_element_info_alter(array &$types) {
  if (isset($types['table'])) {
    $types['table']['#attached']['library'][] = 'my_assets/fancy';
  }
}
```

from the guide ["Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 module"](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module) but it does not work. The hook itself and the condition works. The question is where I have to save the `#attached` array in the `$types` variable?

I appreciate your help and feedback.

PS: The following hook attaches the CSS as expected:

```
function my_assets_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
  $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'my_assets/fancy';
}
```

Edit: While using the site I noticed that my CSS loads on sites like "/admin/structure/types". The Twig Debug hint says "THEME HOOK: 'table'". I guess this is important because it does not say this on the other tables I was waiting for to load the CSS.

Comment: You could try `$types['#attached']['library'][] = 'my_assets/fancy';`, but before even doing that, are you sure that the code is passing the `if (isset($types['table'])) {` statement?

Comment: Also, remember to flush the cache after adding a new hook so drupal picks it up.

Comment: @NoSssweat I already tried your suggestion but with no success. The code passes the if and I dumped the $type variable right after I added my string to it and it really contains the string but still does not load the CSS.

Comment: the other tables I was waiting for to load the CSS ... is it possible you render the theme directly with `'#theme' => 'table'`, which wouldn't use the table render element?

Comment: How do you actually print your tables?

Comment: @leymannx I just created a new Basic Page and used the CKEditor element to insert a table... My task is to attach the CSS on every page where a table is printed. How can I achieve this if not with the mentioned methods? And pages like "/admin/content" are using tables but there is no "THEME HOOK: 'table'", too.

Comment: That's crucial information and actually is a completely different question.

Comment: My first sentence states that I want to attach the CSS if the page contains a table. Though I see now that in the guide it is described that their solution is for #type = table. But how can I solve my (completely different) question? I appreciate every hint.

Comment: Question isn’t accurate anymore because it just asks how to add CSS when content contains a table tag, not rendering a table ELEMENT which are two completely different things.

Comment: You need to rewrite your question completely. The instructions you are following are when you are using the Drupal theming system. What you want is to add a CSS when you add content that includes an HTML table tag inserted directly in the content field (the field you edit with CKEditor). In that case, Drupal doesn't use its theming system for the inner content of that field, only for the field wrapper. So, your question is more related to conditionally theming CKEditor content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### `'#type' => 'table'`

OK, so I tried it out in a Vanilla D8.6 with a custom module like yours and the Bartik theme enabled. I placed [`hook_element_info_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_element_info_alter/8.2.x) in the custom module and checked what Kint `ksm($info)` would return me (matching the code from your question that would be `ksm($types)`). I visited the front page and I saw `'table'` in the array so I thought there must be a table on that page somewhere and the library should get attached. But it didn't. Because there actually was no table.

Only after I added a custom block to the custom module, placed the block somewhere prominent and let it output some sample code from [`class Table`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!Element!Table.php/class/Table):

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function build() {
  $build = [];
  $build['contacts'] = [
    '#type'    => 'table',
    '#caption' => $this
      ->t('Sample Table'),
    '#header'  => [
      $this
        ->t('Name'),
      $this
        ->t('Phone'),
    ],
  ];
  return $build;
}
```

And then the library suddenly got attached as documented. So, yeah, everything's fine. You just need to be sure you really have a `'#type' => 'table'` element on that page. That's all.

---

#### `'#theme' => 'table'`

As @4k4 asked in the comments to your question it seems likely you used `'#theme' => 'table'` to build your tables. Then attach the library directly like that (snipped copied from the Node core module):

```
$build['node_revisions_table'] = [
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#rows' => $rows,
  '#header' => $header,
  '#attached' => [
    'library' => ['node/drupal.node.admin'],
  ],
  '#attributes' => ['class' => 'node-revision-table'],
];
```

Although in this case you could also make use of `hook_preprocess_table` to have that pattern applied to all tables you've built using `'#theme' => 'table'`.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function my_assets_preprocess_table(&$variables) {
  $variables['#attached']['library'][] =  'my_assets/fancy';
}
```

---

#### `<table>`

OK, so after we finally found out you put a table as markup into the body field of your node, using CKEditor, here's what's needed to attach your library accordingly.

You can't check for `'#type' => 'table'` or `'#theme' => 'table'` at this point, as your table is just markup. So simply check for the existence of a `<table>` tag. Or even better, check for just `<table`, because who knows what else attributes can come after that. Pay attention for the **two** underscores in the function name, and replace `body` with the machine name of whatever field you need to preprocess.

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_field__FIELD_NAME().
 */
function my_assets_preprocess_field__body(&$variables) {

  /** @var \Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface $items */
  $items = $variables['element']['#items'];

  $value = $items->first()->getValue()['value'];

  if (\strpos($value, '<table') !== FALSE) {
    $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'my_assets/fancy';
  }
}
```

Comment: @leymannx I tried your hook with no success. The hook does not get called. I tried "my_assets_preprocess(&$variables, $hook) {[...]}" and it works (but for all pages). Why is it not working and especially why does it not work like it is written in the guide? Hope you can help me with further tips.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your effort! I understood now that the type has to be "table". But how do I take into account every table? For example on "/admin/content".

Comment: You’re better off just including the CSS for tables by default as there’s no reason to jump through all these hoops.